# Why does the http domains redirect but not the https domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redirect, https, dns

I have a Ruby on Rails application hosted on Heroku which provides the SSL certificate for the app. This is how the domain routing is setup.

```
http://example.com       -->   https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com   -->   Heroku DNS URL
```

At the Heroku DNS URL the RoR application is set to force SSL so it switches all incoming `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

```
https://www.example.com  -->   Shows RoR app as secure and offers the SSL cert from heroku.
```

As of right now, these three domains all work that a user can type them in and they will be redirected to the secure site.

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

But, if a user types in `https://example.com` they get an error message saying that the server cannot be found. I am at a loss on how to change this as my domain registrar is only for domains, not hosting, so I can't set up an `.htaccess` nor a `.php` redirect.

Can anyone offer some insight on how to fix this, please? And thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is specific to Heroku: https://help.heroku.com/NH44MODG/my-root-domain-isn-t-working-what-s-wrong

However, depending on who your DNS provider is, they might have an option to set up a redirect for you. There are various terms for this, including alias, or ANAME. You can't use a CNAME record on the base domain as that will likely cause other issues, and it goes against RFC.

Some hosting providers allow you to associate both the base domain and the www subdomain with the site so that you don't need a redirect and both will work fine as they are. I'm not sure if Heroku supports that though.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is the issue. My DNS provider is set up to redirect the mail domain to `https://www.example.com`. But, it only does that for `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com`. When a `https` is added to the domain ie `https://example.com` the redirect does not occur. I am confused about this because it works with `http://example.com`. Thank you for your insight, @Benjamin

Comment: That same behavior is reported in the above link, which was why I assumed it was a Heroku specific issue. There should be technically no issue redirecting from https to https like that. Without looking at the specific setup and knowing exactly who the domain is delegated to it is difficult to troubleshoot. Here's a basic rundown of where I would start.
1. Check your nameservers on your domain and make sure they are with the DNS provider you expect.
2. Check the A record on the base domain and see who is hosting it using a reverse DNS lookup.

Double checking those things helps a lot.

Comment: Then when you know for sure where the redirect is happening, you can see if it is possible to make changes. If the redirect is in fact happening at the DNS provider, then we need to check their documentation to see what can be done. If nothing can be done on their end, then you still should have options. You should still be able to change the A record to another host and perform the redirect independently.

Many sites these days don't use the www subdomain exclusively, and modern browsers tend to mask that www subdomain from view in the address bar, so you may prefer to leave it as is.